# Serializable Exception in Autocomplete configured JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jtable, serializable

I have a `JTable` and one column of this table is using a `JComboBox` as an editor. That way it worked fine. I then went on to use [this jar file here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadswingx162jar.htm) to enable autocmplete in my `JComboBox`.Again that worked fine.

Now that I want to save the data from the table as shown below;

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        File outFile= new File("qoutatio.dat");
        try {
            FileOutputStream fous=new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            ObjectOutputStream obj=new ObjectOutputStream(fous);
            obj.writeObject(table);
            obj.flush();
            obj.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
};
```

The program is generating the following error:

```
run:
 Feb 09, 2015 2:13:54 PM quotationGenerator.MainWindow$2 actionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteComboBoxEditor
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.writeObject(JComboBox.java:1569)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

This is showing that one of the classes in the jar file is not `Serializable`.Understood.My question: Is there a way of making this `Serializable`? How do we solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create your own class that extends `org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteComboBoxEditor` and implements `Serializable` and the set this class as the editor on your combobox.